# AngularJs gives WRONG result when multiply by 100

Tags: javascript, angularjs

rank.js

```
$scope.ranks = [{id: 1, rank:1, cost:0.01, days: 3},
    {id: 2, rank:2, cost:0.009, days: 3},
    {id: 3, rank:3, cost:0.008, days: 3},
    {id: 4, rank:4, cost:0.007, days: 3},
    {id: 5, rank:5, cost:0.006, days: 3},
    {id: 6, rank:6, cost:0.005, days: 3},
    {id: 7, rank:7, cost:0.004, days: 3},
    {id: 8, rank:8, cost:0.003, days: 3},
    {id: 9, rank:9, cost:0.002, days: 3},
    {id: 10, rank:10, cost:0.001, days: 3}
    ]
```

rank.html

```
     <div ng-repeat="rank in ranks">
            <h2>លេខរៀងទី {{rank.rank}} សេវា {{rank.cost * 100}}% = ${{100 * rank.cost}}</h2>            
            <p>Rank Number {{rank.rank}} Fee {{rank.cost * 100}}% = ${{100 * rank.cost}}</p>
            <p>កន្លែងមិនទំនេរ Not Available</p>     
     </div>
```

In Browser: rank.html

Why does rank number 2 and 4 produce wrong result? How can I fix it?

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: The problem is not AngularJS; it is how floating-point numbers work in JavaScript. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004 for more.

Comment: Try `${{data.price * rank.cost | number}}`

Comment: hey Vineet, working great!

Answer (score 2):

You should filter your digits first by using [`number`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/number) filter

> If the input is null or undefined, it will just be returned. If the
>   input is infinite (Infinity/-Infinity) the Infinity symbol '∞' is
>   returned. If the input is not a number an empty string is returned.

```
${{data.price * rank.cost | number}}
```

You can pass fraction size too. like

```
 ${{data.price * rank.cost | number : 2}}
```

Comment: it doesn't work when I change the value of data price to 100

Comment: Show me your syntax please.

Comment: <p>Rank Number {{rank.rank}} Fee {{rank.cost * 100 | number : 2}}% = ${{data.price * rank.cost}}</p>

Comment: try `{{(rank.cost * 100) | number : 2}}% = ${{data.price * rank.cost}}`

Comment: Working great now! Thanks

Comment: Now you can understand what you were missing before, right.